# How can I map a xmlns and a clr-namespace in .NET 6.0 like XmlnsDefinitionAttribute?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

I used `System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` in .NET Framework 4.7.2 before and I cannot find the corresponding type in .NET 6.0.

[MSDN - XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) says that it is not supported in .NET 6.0.

How can I map a XAML namespace to a clr-namespace in .NET 6.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF was part of the monolithic .NET Framework. Since .NET Core it was split up into separate runtimes, see [downloads](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) for an overview. Since then there is a core runtime that does not include WPF and a *Destop Runtime* that does (there is a separate *ASP.NET Runtime* as well). In the documentation, when you read *Windows Desktop*, the *.NET Desktop Runtime* is meant, so yes, the attribute is included in .NET 6 according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

[image]